# Orthogonality v. Perpendicularity

Tags: linear-algebra, definition, orthogonality

In Intro to Linear Algebra (my class) two vectors are defined to be *orthogonal* if their dot product is zero. And the dot product of two $n$-vectors $\vec a\cdot\vec b=0$ means that the two vectors are *perpendicular* provided that $\vec a\neq\vec0,\vec b\neq \vec0$. But what if the dot product is between a non-zero vector and the zero vector, are the non-zero vector and zero vector still considered considered orthogonal even though they are not perpendicular? Wikipedia defines orthogonality to be perpendicular.

Comment: In general, only few people say that two vectors are "perpendicular". Perpendicularity is used in geometry when talking about lines, not vectors. Orthogonality is the one used for vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia also says that orthogonality is generalizing that idea into $n$ dimensions. I only hear people say perpendicular when they are talking about 2-3 dimensions. In which case they are the same thing.

I think the zero vector is usually considered orthogonal to every other vector. You could say that the zero vector is perpendicular to every other vector, but I think when people use that term they view the zero vector as a case that doesn't come up (e.g. lines of non zero length), so typical try to omit the situation in the definition.

Comment: Orthogonal is a more generalized concept, applying to functions such as sin/cos in fourier analysis, or polynomials too ( I guess you can think of them as elements of a vector space too). Also , orthogonal can apply to curvilinear systems, so we can speak of a orthogonal reference frame, say on a torus or other manifolds , where a coordinate system of non-straight lines can be considered point wise orthogonal.